# Why does a SYN or FIN bit in a TCP segment consume a byte in the sequence number space?

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols

I am trying to understand the rationale behind such a design.  I skimmed through a few RFCs but did not find anything obvious.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not particularly subtle - it's so that the SYN and FIN bits themselves can be acknowledged (and therefore re-sent if they're lost).

For example, if the connection is closed without sending any more data, then if the FIN did *not* consume a sequence number the closing end couldn't tell the difference between an ACK for the FIN, and an ACK for the data that was sent prior to the FIN.

Comment: If one were to specify that anything that opens a connection must send a 00 byte at the start of the connection (which the receiver should ignore) and another 00 at the end (which the receiver should again ignore) would that have basically the same semantics as the SYN/FIN bits, but at the expense of transmitting two more bytes with each connection?

Comment: Supercat: What would you then do if the data in the stream started or ended with a null byte?

Comment: For starting, the first packet sent by the party responding to the initial SYN would have a sequence number equal to that received in the SYN, rather than equal to that plus one; a recipient would thus regard the first byte of that packet as being a useless retransmission.  For ending, the protocol would have to have been defined to explicitly say that the last byte of transmission should be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

SYNs and FINs require acknowledgement, thus they increment the stream's sequence number by one when used.

Comment: Does not answer the question since replying with (ACK) the same received sequence number can also acknowledge.

Comment: @SteveZ: FINs take up a byte of sequence number. If host A sends a packet with SEQ 1, no data, and the FIN flag set and host B sends an ACK of 1, host B did not acknowledge the FIN.